# Can I realistically use Forestry without Buildcraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

> Forestry is a large Minecraft mod which adds new items, machines, and ores to the game, many of which are used in farming. Forestry also adds bees, beekeeping, and bee breeding. It was designed for compatibility with IndustrialCraft 2 and BuildCraft 3, and *many of its machines require power from BuildCraft compatible engines.*

Forestry sounds interesting, but I'm not at all interested in buildcraft. Can I realistically use forestry without buildcraft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long story short?

No.

Forestry relies on Buildcraft being present.

Comment: you could use TE for the power transfer

Comment: Who cares? He'll probably have too much fun breeding trees.

Comment: and don't forget bees!

Comment: bees are actually what I'm most interested in in forestry

Comment: @Jeffreylin_ I care, as that's a solid answer to my question, whats this about power transfer?

Comment: @Ender: By referencing an electric range in my answer I seem to have given the impression that there's a power problem in using Forestry without Buildcraft; which there isn't. The problem is one of pipes, which are easily the best and most important feature of Buildcraft.

Comment: I dont plan on using the pipes or most of the automation process at all. I'm not interested in automation in the least.

Comment: Forestry REQUIRES buildcraft. I tried running it without and got an error msg specifying 'where is buildcraft?'

Comment: @Ender: Well, there it is then. Answer updated.

Comment: @Ender why don't you just not use what you don't want and use what you do?

Comment: @Jeffereylin_ Because sometimes I dont have a choice, this example being prevelant in that notion.

Comment: Strange, that it doesn't run without buildcraft, as the mod developer had updated it to not necessarily require buildcraft.
Perhaps it is the wrong version, or the config files are incorrect or any other kind of problem. It SHOULD have been possible, and nothing in the mod documentation suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Tally if it helps any i'm using the FTB version of the mod, which is likely not the most updated version.

Answer (score -1):

Forestry does not require buildcraft to play and there are many mods that have buildcraft energynet integration.

To be honest I do believe that You can play only forestry and be happy with it. Forestry do also provide own buildcraft engine, so there is no problem in powering your machines. If you have installed also railcraft or thermal expansion or Mekanism or Power Converters or similiar BC compatible mod, you can freely skip buildcraft.

Even using a forestry engines it is possible to have some fun with forestry. Cause those engines do run for a quite time when provided with fuel.

Wiki tells us that one peat in peat engine do run for 5000 ticks and that is 4,16 seconds, so whole stack will run for 262.4 seconds (that is 4.37 minutes), and full engine that can hold 4 four stacks of peat do run for 1049.6 seconds, and that is 17.49 minutes. That isn't really bad. When we also add hoppers... Well you could make a hell of a run. And that is one of the basic engines.

Also most of forestry machines don't eat out a lot of energy, so we don't need top tier engines from other mods.

Also forestry do have it's own world gen, so every raw resource that is used in forestry is also provided by forestry.

Also none of the forestry machine does require to be operated by other mods machines.

Also forestry does even give ability to transport not whole buckets of liquids, by item called pipet.

But to sum up. Buildcraft is not required to be happy with forestry.

Comment: I tried it out and you actually cannot, Minecraft won't even run. You get an error msg.

Comment: If you are getting an error msg that means that you did something terribly wrong. To prof that it is possible to run mc with only forestry: http://i.imgur.com/54YIdzh.png And it does works perfectly. Also Forestry is a stand alone mod for years. I only heard rumors that it was a BC plugin, but never seen that for my own eyes.

Comment: Are you running the FTB forestry? Cause I am, and that's a major point in the argument.

Comment: Why you download a modpack to use one mod? FTB is a modpack that is build from separate mods, so versions can vary from what I am using and what is in FTB. Still, I never did heard about any extra content, or special versions for FTB only.

Comment: Actually there is only one dependency that forestry do require, it's Forge. But that is true for 99% mods for minecraft.

Comment: how about I remove buildcraft, and show you the screenshot, will that make you happy? It seems simpler than explaining the numerous amount of ways you've misunderstood me. Ill do so in a bit.